# How to implement KB id for pages in XWiki?

Tags: xwiki

Is there any way to navigate xwiki pages using automatically incrementing KnowledgeBase ID. Like in Microsoft Support https://support.microsoft.com/kb/825751 -- every article has its own unique numeric searchable ID.

Requirements:

- KB ID should be automatically incremented when new page has been created (no manual inc)
- Ability to find pages by their KB ID (from search form)
- KB ID should be displayed on page or placed in page URL
- Pages should have normal text titles

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: there is the wiki page history ... admittedly the older page versions are not searched by default, and urls are not "updated" (there is no such thing as a "KB ID" for a wiki page in XWiki, at least not by default). I guess one could try to write an extension which listens to "DocumentUpdatingEvent" and generated / maintains a list of "KB ID" -> page version mappings ...